# GitLab CI with Fastlane and Cocoapods not working

Tags: continuous-integration, realm, gitlab, cocoapods, fastlane

I can't get GitLab CI to work with Fastlane and Cocoapods.

Here is the error messages I get during the Gitlab-CI:

[image]

```rb
[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.
```

Here the screenshot of the GitLab CI Log:

[image]

[image]

Here is my gitlab-runner register code that I write into a MacOS Terminal:

```rb
sudo gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token "ABCDEFG21sadfSAEGEAERE" \
  --description "MyApp runner with shell" \
  --tag-list ios \
  --executor "shell"
```

After that I type inside the terminal:

```rb
sudo gitlab-runner start
```

and...

```rb
sudo gitlab-runner run
```

After the `run` cmd, any git push will cause the GitLab CI to start a new Pipeline. So far, so good :)

But after a few seconds, the above error occurs. And it has to do with the Cocoapods.

**How can you make Gitlab (and/or Fastlane) to recognise the Podfile during CI ??**

Here is my Fastfile:

```rb
update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

    def install_pods
        cocoapods(
          clean: true,
          podfile: "./Podfile",
          try_repo_update_on_error: true
        )
    end

    lane :tests do
        install_pods()
        gym(configuration: "Release",
            workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
            scheme: "MyApp",
            clean: true,
            output_name: "MyApp.ipa")  
        # increment_build_number
        scan(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
            devices: ["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS"],
            scheme: "MyAppTests")
    end
```

I tried plenty of other Podfile paths, and even tried to run everything on a docker container. But same thing, the error `[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root` remains. What is wrong here ??

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```rb
stages:
  - unit_tests

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

unit_tests:
  dependencies: []
  stage: unit_tests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane tests
  tags:
    - ios
```

Any help appreciated. How do you make the Podfile being recognised by the CI ???

Comment: "You cannot run CocoaPods as root." - Dont run as root i.e. dont use `sudo`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please specify where not to use `sudo`. Do you mean to use `gitlab-runner start` and `gitlab-runner run` instead ?? The problem with `gitlab-runner run` (without sudo) is that in this case, the CI-Pipeline never starts for some reason. Can you make an example of what you mean exactly ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to run any part of this as an admin user. Make a mistake as a correctly configured/restricted user and it might not be that bad. do it as root and you could cause serious damage to your machine/server. run everything without sudo and if it complains, investigate why it needs it. You might just need to change ownership/access permissions on certain files/folders

Comment: If I do `gitlab-runner run` instead of `sudo gitlab-runner run` then I end up with a the message `New runner: Has not connected yet` on my Gitlab-CI-settings. The runner does not seem to start or connect (and my Terminal only shows and freezes with `Listen address not defined`). How can I get the gitlab-runner to run without sudo ????? What permissions need to be set and where? (I am on MacOS)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my problem by adding -user option. Like

`sudo gitlab-runner run -user <my_username>`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution:

Also your `gitlab-runner register` is not allowed to have `sudo`.

For some reason there are many tutorials out there that show differently (i.e. with `sudo`) - such as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMgeSW5LX5c) or others...

Anyway, as [@Scriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779527/scriptable) pointed out, on a Mac you absolutely need to leave sudo out !

[Here is the best tutorial I have found](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/03/06/ios-publishing-with-gitlab-and-fastlane/#comment-4401018524) on how to Gitlab CI an iOS project.

Comment: I'm not running as sudo and still, it's not working, any ideas?

Comment: I have this problem on Gitlab Server CI, any solutions for that?