# GitLab CI with Docker, Fastlane and Cocoapods not working

Tags: docker, realm, gitlab, cocoapods, fastlane

Desperate help needed:

Already asked for the case with `gitlab-runner register` as "shell", I try to ask a very similar question here with `gitlab-runner register` as "docker".

Since 3 days I try to get Gitlab CI running (using docker, fastlane - all for an iOS-app having Cocoapods dependencies).

Here is the error message that the GitLab CI spits out:

[image]

I did the following steps:

1. install fastlane ([link to fastlane page](https://fastlane.tools))
2. create a GitLab project and upload your project repository ([link to GitLab](https://gitlab.com))
3. install gitlab-runner on MacOS, [following these steps...](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/osx.html)
4. install Docker (for desktop), [registering here and downloading the app](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac)
5. register gitlab-runner (i.e. open terminal and type the following):
   (your Token can be found under GitLab-->Settings-->CI/CD)

```rb
sudo gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token "TOKENABCDEFG" \
  --description "MyApp runner with ruby-2.6" \
  --tag-list ios \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image ruby:2.6
```

6. start docker application on your Mac
7. run docker image (by typing the following in your terminal:)

```rb
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /Users/Shared/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

After all that, any git push to your GitLab project repo will automatically start a Pipeline.

I also tried using a local shell (instead of docker) - but no success either [as documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381303/gitlab-ci-with-fastlane-and-cocoapods-not-working).

No matter what I try, I always end up with the same error message:

[image]

```rb
[08:48:04]: Driving the lane 'ios tests' 
[08:48:04]: -----------------------
[08:48:04]: --- Step: cocoapods ---
[08:48:04]: -----------------------
[08:48:04]: Using deprecated option: '--clean' (true)
[08:48:04]: $ cd '.' && bundle exec pod install
[08:48:04]: ▸ WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
[08:48:04]: ▸ Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:
[08:48:04]: ▸ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
[08:48:04]: ▸ 
[08:48:04]: ▸ bundler: failed to load command: pod (/usr/local/bundle/bin/pod)
[08:48:04]: ▸ CLAide::Help: [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.
```

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```rb
stages:
  - unit_tests

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

before_script:
  - gem install bundler
  - bundle install

unit_tests:
  dependencies: []
  stage: unit_tests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fastlane/screenshots
      - fastlane/logs
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane tests
  tags:
    - ios
```

And here the Fastfile:

```rb
update_fastlane

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

    def install_pods
        cocoapods(
          clean: true,
          podfile: "./Podfile",
          try_repo_update_on_error: true
        )
    end

    lane :tests do
        install_pods()
        gym(configuration: "Release",
            workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
            scheme: "MyApp",
            clean: true,
            output_name: "MyApp.ipa")
        # increment_build_number
        scan(workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
            devices: ["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS"],
            scheme: "MyAppTests")
    end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitLab CI with Fastlane and Cocoapods not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381303/gitlab-ci-with-fastlane-and-cocoapods-not-working)

Comment: It is a very similar question, I agree. However, what is new here is the fact that I tried  the gitlab ci working with Docker (which is not the case in the other entry)...

Comment: You are still running CocoaPods as root, which doesn't work as the error message tells you. Find a way not to do that (which could be via asking a question that helps you understand how this is run via sudo, how you can change that or similar).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I realised I did a terrible mistake by calling `sudo gitlab-runner register ...` instead of `gitlab-runner register...`. But now (leaving docker and going back to shell -  since some article propose shell for iOS projects...) - I have the next problem which is a `Permission denied` error. It seems that gitlab tries to make a directory called `builds`. I did set the permissions to read&write for the location gitlab tries to mkdir. But it still does not work. Any idea on how to solve this permission issue ??

Comment: No, as I am not going to try to understand what is going on. Create a new question that includes (only!) the relevant information and I am sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I did so [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399687/gitlab-ci-ios-project-issue-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution:

Your `gitlab-runner register` is not allowed to have `sudo`.

For some reason there are many tutorials out there that show differently (i.e. with sudo) - such as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMgeSW5LX5c) or others...

Anyway, on a Mac you absolutely need to leave sudo out and absolutely register as "shell" executor for GitLab (i.e. not "docker")

[Here is the best tutorial I have found](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/03/06/ios-publishing-with-gitlab-and-fastlane/#comment-4401018524) on how to Gitlab CI an iOS project.