# how to set up GitLab CI for iOS project

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, gitlab, cocoapods, gitlab-ci

Is there a most recent and detailed-enough tutorial out there on how to set up a CI for an iOS project using **Gitlab** ?

I found many tutorials (see list below) - but it seems that things have changed at GitLab since these tutorials were made. Or they are simply not detailed and well-enough explained for me as a beginner. Therefore I wonder if there is a most accurate step-by-step explanation on how to set Gitlab-CI up for iOS on a Mac ?

**In particular, I am looking for a Gitlab-CI step-by-step tutorial for an iOS project using Fastlane and having Cocoapods Dependencies.**

Below you find the list of tutorials and pages that all say things about GitLab CI setup for iOS projects.

(I've followed all of them - but none is detailed enough for me as a beginner in CI or, really, is no longer accurate for 2019 and what GitLab represents today).

For all of the tutorials, I end up with Gitlab Pipeline errors.

Here a list of my open stackoverflow questions, each with its own Gitlab CI trial:

- `gitlab-runner register` without sudo: I end up with "permission denied"
  [Stackoverflow Nr1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399687/gitlab-ci-ios-project-issue-permission-denied)
- `gitlab-runner register` with docker: I end up with "root error" [Stackoverflow Nr2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393974/gitlab-ci-with-docker-fastlane-and-cocoapods-not-working)
- `sudo gitlab-runner register` with sudo: I end up with "root error" [Stackoverflow Nr 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381303/gitlab-ci-with-fastlane-and-cocoapods-not-working)

Concrete questions:

1. can you use "docker" with Gitlab for iOS ? (or must it be "shell")
2. do you need to use the "sudo" word or not for your gitlab-runner registration ? (why or why not)
3. how do you set permissions on your Mac so that Gitlab CI works once you leave all sudo words out ?

Here is the list of tutorials I've found that explain Gitlab CI with iOS projects:

- [Setting up GitLab CI for iOS projects](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/10/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-projects/)
- [How to set up GitLab Continuous Integration for iOS projects without a hassle](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-set-up-gitlab-continuous-integration-for-ios-projects-without-a-hustle-53c2b642c90f)
- [How to set up GitLab CI for iOS in three relatively simple steps](https://medium.com/static-object/how-to-set-up-gitlab-ci-for-ios-in-a-few-relatively-simple-steps-56a0d88d0272)
- [iOS Project (CI/CD): Integrating GitLab-CI, Fastlane, HockeyApp, and AppCenter](https://dzone.com/articles/ios-project-integrating-gitlab-ci-fastlane-amp-hoc-1)

Comment: Hi @iKK, did you find any solution of this?

Comment: uff sorry - no - it's been 3 years since I have last used GitLab. I do not have a solution today. But please check my [below response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55424338/3826232)

Answer (score 5):

[Here is the best tutorial on how to set up GitLab CI for an iOS-project](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/03/06/ios-publishing-with-gitlab-and-fastlane/#comment-4401018524) that I have found.

Here are the findings that lead to a successful GitLab CI for an iOS-project:

- It is especially important to recognise that as for an iOS-project,
  your GitLab CI must be registered as "shell" executor (not "docker").
- Also, you are not allowed to use any `sudo` when dealing with the
  gitlab-runner. (no `sudo` allowed whatsoever since Apple wants you to
  have a user-mode connection with GitLab (and no system-mode as in a
  docker or else)...

The steps are as follows:

`gitlab-runner stop` (optional if already previous trials...)

`gitlab-runner uninstall`  (optional if already previous trials...)

```rb
gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token "ABCDEFG21sadfSAEGEAERE" \
  --description "MyApp runner with shell" \
  --tag-list ios \
  --executor "shell"
```

(feel free to use different tags. Also, the token can be found under the GitLab page-->under Settings-->CI/CD-->Runner expand)

`gitlab-runner install`

`gitlab-runner start`

Furthermore, it turned out that the "permission denied" error on my GitLab Pipeline had nothing to do with GitLab itself - but was due to a Ruby version mismatch on my Mac that I connected with the gitlab-runner.

I was able to update my Ruby version [with the help of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25716203/3826232) (i.e. using `chruby`). There are other possibilities out there on how to update Ruby on your Mac.

It is important to understand that GitLab requires your Mac to have a stable Ruby environment.